# Crash when using boost serialize a lot of times

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am making a program that serialize a struct of data and send it to the server. The problems come to when the function that serialize fails when it has been use, more or less 40 times or so.

I am using **Visual Studio Community 2015**, **boost 1.59 32bits** and **winsock2**, the program is compiled with 32 bits architecture.

The error is:

> Exception produced in 0x772BE3C6 (ntdll.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading the location 0x3838E1A9.

And here is a simple example using the function that crash:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

struct StructFunction 
{
    char function;
    int arguments;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & function;
        ar & arguments;
    }
};
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(StructFunction, boost::serialization::object_serializable)

bool Send(std::string buffer)
{
    int iResult = send(ConnectSocket, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 0);

    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        Stop();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int SerializeAndSend(StructFunction structFunction)
{
    // serialize obj into an std::string
    std::string serial_str;
    serial_str.clear();

    boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string> inserter(serial_str);
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string> > 
        s(inserter);
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(s); // This throws the error

    oa << structFunction;

    // flush the stream to finish writing into the buffer
    s.flush();

    Send(serial_str);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ConnectSocket = /* We create a socket that is connected to the server using winsock2 */

    StructFunction structFunction;
    structFunction.function = "A";
    structFunction.parameter = 1;

    SerializeAndSend(structFunction);
}
```

In the real code the function **SerializeAndSend** is called 40 times aprox.

I can say, 90% for sure, that the serialized struct is initialized and did not had any wrong value.

I have try to clean the projects in the client and the server. The RAM they use is very low, 13mb more or less.

I do not know why it fails when it has been use and not in the first time.

Comment: I'd start looking at the 10% you didn't check. Also, we can't see anything at all here because we have no idea what `Bar_function` is or how it is serialized. FWIW there could be a resource leak (in the surrounding code, like `Send`, perhaps)

Comment: Try to make it a SSCCE. See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.

Comment: @sehe I have added a sample code.

Comment: Excellent start. It's not very accurate, but these were minor nit-picks. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of eliminating causes, is to make the thing very self-contained and just observe whether it still reproduces the/a problem:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d7236f5649548a7)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/back_inserter.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/array.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

struct StructFunction 
{
    char function;
    int arguments;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
    {
        ar & function;
        ar & arguments;
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(StructFunction, boost::serialization::object_serializable)

bool Send(std::string buffer)
{
/*
 *    int iResult = send(ConnectSocket, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), 0);
 *
 *    if(iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
 *    {
 *        printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
 *        Stop();
 *        return false;
 *    }
 */

    return true;
}

int SerializeAndSend(StructFunction structFunction)
{
    // serialize obj into an std::string
    std::string serial_str;

    namespace bio = boost::iostreams;

    {
        bio::stream<bio::back_insert_device<std::string> > s(serial_str);
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(s);
        oa << structFunction;
    }

    static bool do_init = true;
    if (do_init) {
        std::cout << "DEBUG: \n";
        for (uint8_t ch : serial_str)
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::showbase << std::hex << static_cast<int>(ch) << " ";
        do_init = false;
    }

    Send(serial_str);

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    //ConnectSocket = [> We create a socket that is connected to the server using winsock2 <]

    for (auto i = 0ull; i< 1ull << 22; ++i) {
        StructFunction structFunction;
        structFunction.function = 'A';
        structFunction.arguments = 1;

        SerializeAndSend(structFunction);
    }
}
```

As you can see, not a lot of trouble, output:

```
DEBUG: 
0x16 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0x73 0x65 0x72 0x69 0x61 0x6c 0x69 0x7a 0x61 0x74 0x69 0x6f 0x6e 0x3a 0x3a 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x69 0x76 0x65 0xd 00 0x4 0x8 0x4 0x8 0x1 00 00 00 0x41 0x1 00 00 00 
real    0m24.026s
user    0m24.010s
sys 0m0.000s
```

### What Next?

Try it on *your* system. If it's ok, then the problem is in `Send` (and related functions).

If you see the problem on your platform, consider (memory) profiling and enabling the debug heap for diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I am not in the work space at this time, I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: I have try it in my system and it works ok, well, it did not end never the for loop, but it never crash.

I am going to check the `Send` and check the memory.

Comment: It cannot never end (barring compiler bugs). If it's too slow, just decrease the `22` (because it's a huge number of iterations). You could check with a Release build (it's unexpected for it to take very much longer than, say, a minute)

Comment: I was doing some test and I realize that the class were are all these methods and variables is a `singleton` created using `static std::unique_ptr<NameOfClass>` and `static std::once_flag`. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Please just show the relevant code as a SSCCE. Using variables is not a problem. Global variables are also variables. The problem ***could***, of course, be in **how** you use them, but you're not telling me that.

Comment: I made a full sample of how it is in the real code but I test it and it works fine. Then I was testing the full code and it came to work. So, I finally realize that the error is something that I am carrying from another part. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I finally found the error. It was in another part of the code near where this function is called. It was that I was not allocating the enough memory in a buffer.

Comment: Classic buffer overflow. Good work finding it! As you can see, rigorous elimination of possible causes always works (the process of elimination just might be hard some of the time).